# How to set the computer hostname (not MAC address) to a static IP on a router?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I am using a [Dovado PRO AC](https://www.dovado.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/pro_ac_manual_910.pdf) router and want to set my computer to have a static IP address but I don’t want to use my MAC address for that but instead use the hostname as this image shown

The problem is it's not working. I think I am using the wrong hostname `SAMSUNG-TV-8`, which is my laptop Windows 10 name.

Do you see on my image in my question, it say "hostname" mydomain.example. I see the same doing ipconfig/all. What is that all about it sure look like a hostname

Where do I get the hostname from?

> [image]

Comment: AFAIK Windows use the "PC/Computer Name" as hostname: https://www.isunshare.com/images/article/windows-10/see-computer-name-in-windows-10/check-computer-name-in-about.png

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows 10 PC the easiest way to determine the hostname is to open the Properties of "This PC" In Explorer. It is listed there as "Computer Name".
To change it use the "Change Settings" links at the right hand side and click on the "Change" button in the next panel. (Admin right required. Computer needs to reboot as too!)

Please note:

1. HOSTNAME based assignment will not always work, depending on numerous things that can go wrong. You may have to go for Mac-address anyway.
2. It is possible that your router wants to hostname to be in either "ALL CAPS" or "all lowercase". You may have to change the hostname in Windows to follow the same logic.

Comment: Do you see on my image in my question, it say "hostname" mydomain.example. I see the same [here](https://snipboard.io/paAWnr.jpg) when doing ipconfig/all. What is that all about it sure look like a hostname